# Stuck with compute shader in Android 5.1.1 (Opengl 3.1)

Tags: android, opengl-es, compute-shader

I have written very simple program to get values from compute shader and render it directly on to the screen.

I am suspecting that the shader storage buffer is not being binded to my vbo after I call all necessary compute shader methods.

I am sharing the code please see if there are some errors. No compilation error I am getting and moreover the device I am using also supports gl 3.1 that I have checked.

And also in addition to all this do we have to mention anything in manifest?

This is my renderer code

```html
public class MyRenderer implements Renderer{
 
 Context context;
 int ProgramId;
 int ComputeShaderProgramId;
 int aPositionLocation;
 int aColorLocation;
 int radiusLocation;
 int gIndexBufferBinding;
 float rad=0;
 int[] vbo = new int[1];
 
 int NUM_VERTS_H = 16;
 int NUM_VERTS_V = 16;
 int GROUP_SIZE_WIDTH = 8;
 int GROUP_SIZE_HEIGHT = 8;
 
 MyRenderer(Context context)
 {
  this.context = context;
  
 }

 @Override
 public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
  GLES31.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 }

 @Override
 public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  String VetrexShaderSource = ShaderHelper.readFile(context, R.raw.vertexshader);
  String FragmentShaderSource = ShaderHelper.readFile(context, R.raw.fragmentshader);
  String ComputeShaderSource = ShaderHelper.readFile(context, R.raw.hellocompute);
  
  int vertexShader = ShaderHelper.compileShader(VetrexShaderSource,GLES31.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  int fragmentShader = ShaderHelper.compileShader(FragmentShaderSource,GLES31.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  int computeShader = ShaderHelper.compileShader(ComputeShaderSource,GLES31.GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);
  
  
  ProgramId = ShaderHelper.createShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
  GLES31.glUseProgram(ProgramId);
  
  
  aPositionLocation = GLES31.glGetAttribLocation(ProgramId, "a_Position");
  aColorLocation = GLES31.glGetAttribLocation(ProgramId, "aColorCoordinate");
  
  ComputeShaderProgramId = ShaderHelper.createComputeShaderProgram(computeShader);
  
  GLES31.glUseProgram(ComputeShaderProgramId);
  gIndexBufferBinding = 1;
  
  GLES31.glGenBuffers(1, vbo,0);
  
 }

 @Override
 public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
  GLES31.glClear(GLES31.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GLES31.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  
  GLES31.glUseProgram(ComputeShaderProgramId);
  GLES31.glBindBufferBase(GLES31.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, gIndexBufferBinding, vbo[0]);

//  GLES31.glDispatchCompute(
//                (NUM_VERTS_H % GROUP_SIZE_WIDTH + NUM_VERTS_H) / GROUP_SIZE_WIDTH,
//                (NUM_VERTS_V % GROUP_SIZE_HEIGHT + NUM_VERTS_V) / GROUP_SIZE_HEIGHT,
//               1);
  

  GLES31.glDispatchCompute(2,1,1);

  GLES31.glBindBufferBase(GLES31.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, gIndexBufferBinding, 0);

  GLES31.glMemoryBarrier(GLES31.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);

  System.out.println("error "+GLES31.glGetError());
  // Bind VBO
  
  GLES31.glBindBuffer( GLES31.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0] );

  // Bind Vertex and Fragment rendering shaders
  GLES31.glUseProgram(ProgramId);
  GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
  
  // Draw points from VBO
  GLES31.glDrawArrays(GLES31.GL_POINTS, 0, 6);
  
  
  
 }

}
```

this is my compute shader (hellocompute)

```html
#version 310 es
layout (local_size_x = 3) in;

layout (std430, binding = 1) buffer Output
{
    float data[];
    
} outBuffer;


void main()
{
    uint ident = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    outBuffer.data[ident] = float(ident)*0.2;
    
    memoryBarrierShared();
    
    barrier();
    
}
```

this is my vertexshader

```html
attribute float a_Position;

void main()
{
    gl_PointSize = 15.0;
      gl_Position = vec4(a_Position,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

this is my fragment shader

```html
precision mediump float;

void main()
{
      //gl_FragColor = vColorCoordinate;
      
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

I should see some yellow dots at x = 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0

But only one dot is seen at x=0 since it is taking the default zero value for attrib a_Position.

New values should reflect when binding to vbo after dispatch call.

Comment: I don't see a `glVertexAttribPointer()` call anywhere.

Comment: I even added a call  GLES31.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 1, GLES31.GL_FLOAT, true, 0, 0); after GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation); still it nothing is displayed on screen.

Comment: Thanks for ur help Reto Koradi. I got my mistake, I was not allocating memory for SSBO. I made a call GLES31.glBufferData(GLES31.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 6*4, null, GLES31.GL_STATIC_DRAW); after bindbufferbase and it worked thanks.